# Allocation time of square matrices

Tags: c++, matrix, allocation, adjacency-matrix

I'm working on a project in C++ that needs to perform some pathfinding on a medium-sized adjacency matrix. These calculations will happen roughly once or twice a minute, and the typical values for V could be as large as 10,000.

Computation time performance is my main concern, not memory performance.

The graph here will always be symmetric, so I know some space can be saved by only using one triangle of the matrix, but still my question:

How can I know at what point it will become speedier to retain this large array in memory and just zero all cells than to continually allocate, use, and deallocate the array? Are there mitigating factors here that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Have you tried measuring it? Run the whole allocate/deallocate a few thousand times in a loop, and measure how long it takes, as well as measure the average. Then check if that time will be noticeable when done a couple of time a minute. My guess is that it won't be big enough to worry about, the processing you do will be the part where you need to think about possible optimizations *after* you measure and profile. Don't do premature optimization.

Comment: I'm definitely going to measure this. In fact I submitted this question mostly to get opinions from people smarter than I am. As far as I can tell I may not be able to significantly improve the processing done to the data, due to organizational politics and what-not.

Comment: Just FYI: Allocating a chunk of memory is O(1). Allocating memory doesn't process the memory in any way (unless you ask it to with e.g. the old C `calloc` function) so the allocation itself is very quick. If you dynamically allocate an array of pointers (i.e. `int**`) then you need a loop to allocate the inner array leading to O(n). The complexity also depends on *what* you allocate, since you're programming in C++ if you allocate objects there may be constructors and things that are called. Same with deallocating (but then destructors are called of course).